# Insert into a 2-3 tree with one single node

Tags: c++, insert

So, I'm trying to build a function for my 2-3 tree class, and this is the pseudocode that I've been following:

```
if T is empty replace it with a single node containing k
else if T is just 1 node m:
    (a) create a new leaf node n containing k
    (b) create a new internal node with m and n as its children,
        and with the appropriate values for leftMax and middleMax
else call auxiliary method insert(T, k)
```

However, I don't understand what it does for the case when T is just 1 single node (or one leaf). What is n ? is it a misprint ? If m is already a root since T is just one node m, then how can it can be create as a new internal node as (b) instructs ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Any drawing would be much easier to understand the concept and I would really appreciate for that. Thank you

Comment: "create a new leaf node n containing k". "n" is the newly created leaf node.

Comment: @molbdnilo: can you draw a picture please ?

Comment: @molbdnilo: so what is the new root now ? isn't it supposed to be the root ? how come m and n become internal nodes ?

Comment: "Draw a picture"? Of what? After a) and b), you'll have a new node that has the old node, "m", and the one you created in a), "n", as its children. The node you create in step b is unnamed.

Comment: @molbdnilo: let's say "h" is the name of the node in step b, what is the value of node "h" ?